# How to make a class object instance to return a predefined value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the rspec-rails 2 gem. I am testing my **controller** code (BTW: I am newbie to rspec) and I would like to make possible that a class object instance returns a predefined value. That is, in my controller I have:

```
def create
  ...

  if @current_user.has_authorization?
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

In order to test the "`else` part" of the `if` statement I would like to make possible that (for the current spec example that I am working on - read below for a sample implementation) the `@current_user.has_authorization?` returns `false`.

**How can I make that?**

---

I tried the following in my spec file, but it seems do not work as expected:

```
it "should have no authorization" do
  @current_user.stub(:has_authorization?).and_return(false)

  # I also tried the following and it still doesn't work
  # @current_user.should_receive(:has_authorization?).and_return(false)

  post :create
  ...
end
```

Comment: What happens if you add a `@current_user.has_authorization?.should be_false` just after your `@current_user.stub...` call?

Comment: @Fabio - It happens that the test passes. Of course, I commented out the `post :create ...` code to make it to work.

Comment: So the problem is not in the stub call, it should be somewhere else, maybe you're changing the `@current_user` value later in the code. To avoid this kind of issues I use mocha as mocking framework, which defines a method named `any_instance` that stub methods for all instances of that class. If you're interested in that I could post that as answer (it's too long as comment).

Comment: @Fabio - I would appreciate if you do that. Rspec and Mocha are very similar... so, I should only find the RSpec method that implement a similar behavior as the `any_instance` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@current_user` in the context of your rspec test is not the same as `@current_user` in the context of your controller.  One is an instance variable, in the instance of your controller class that Rails is running.  The other is an instance variable in your rspec test.

You aren't supposed to poke at your user variable, but rather need to make it so Rails finds a User supplied by the test framework.  Take a look at [this example](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/164640).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that issue you could use [mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/), to do that do the following:

Add the mocha gem to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.

Then change the Rspec mock configuration framework in your `spec_helper.rb` file

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :rspec
end
```

Then in your spec you can do this

```
it "should have no authorization" do
  User.any_instance.stubs(:has_authorization?).returns(false)
  post :create
  ...
end
```

This (or [the correct answer from Coderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590156/how-to-make-a-class-object-instance-to-return-a-predefinited-value/7590421#7590421)) will solve your issue.

Notice that as far as I know there is no `any_instance` equivalent in Rspec mocking functions.

Answer (score 0):

When your spec is running, `self` is pointing to a test object (try `p self` or `puts self.class` inside a spec sometime and see for yourself), so `@current_user` is referring to an instance variable on that test object. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the `@current_user` instance variable on your controller.

One way to do what you want is to create a current_user *method* or *accessor* on your controller, and call it instead of accessing `@current_user` directly. Then you can stub or mock that method from your spec, assuming you can get a pointer to your controller instance.

Another way is to set the `@current_user` variable directly from inside your spec. Again, get a pointer to your controller instance, then do `x = mock("user"); controller.instance_variable_set(:@current_user, x)` then you can mock/stub methods on `x`.